# How to pivot some values in a MySQL table and display separately

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table structure

```
+---------+----------+-------+------------+------------+
| Student | Subject  | Grade |   Marks    | YearID     |
+---------+----------+-------+------------+------------+
| John    | English  | A     |         80 |         15 |
| John    | French   | C     |         94 |         15 |
| Mike    | English  | A     |         31 |         15 |
| Mike    | French   | C     |         73 |         15 |
+---------+----------+------+------------+------------+
```

My problem is I need something like this in MySQL

```
 +---------+----------+------+----------+
 | Student | English  |French | YearID  |
 | John    | 80       | 94    | 15      |
 +---------+----------+------+----------+
```

How do this in a MySQL script

Comment: So `Student` + `Subject` + `YearID` are unique in the table. And there exist either only 'English' and 'French' in `Subject` or at least you only want to select these two subjects.  And you want result rows per `Student` + `YearID` with the two subjects being columns. Is all this correct?

Answer (score 1):

You have rows per `Student` + `Subject` + `YearID` in the table but you want result rows per `Student` + `YearID` only. This means you want to aggregate the data and group by `Student` + `YearID`. Then use `CASE WHEN` to access the correct subject:

```
select 
  student, 
  case when subject = 'English' then marks end as english, 
  case when subject = 'French' then marks end as french, 
  yearid
from mytable
group by student, yearid;
```

This gives you a row per `Student` + `YearID` and picks an English record for the English column and a french record for the French column. As there can be only one English and one French record per `Student` + `YearID` in the table, we don't even need an aggregate function (such as `SUM` or `MAX`) here.

Comment: Check if you have a typo. Do you see the records with `select * from mytable where  subject = 'French'`?

Comment: I checked it twice but still its null only when I execute the query

Comment: So when you ask `where subject = 'French'` you get data and with `case when subject = 'French' then` you don't get them? That seems unlikely. Please try `select case when subject = 'French' then marks end as frenchmarks, case when subject = 'French' then 1 end as frenchrecord, marks from mytable where subject = 'French'`. Are you getting several rows with all 1 for `frenchrecord` and all null for `frenchmarks` and different values for `marks`?